# Gridview: how to restore page position after user clicked

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview control on the page with 10 pages and in that gridview column i have a hyperlink where user can click the link and it will take to different page.

the mainpage.aspx with my gridview control on it:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" Width="100%" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"/>
<Columns>

 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true"> 
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
           <asp:HyperLink id="hlView" runat="server">View Users</asp:HyperLink> 
 </ItemTemplate>
 ......................
 ......................
 .......................


public void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    HyperLink hl = e.Row.FindControl("hlView") as HyperLink;
    Customers t = e.Row.DataItem;
    hl.NavigateUrl = "User.aspx?Id=" + t.Id;
    ..................
    ......................
```

on my User.aspx page

i have

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);return true;">Back To Page</a>
```

my question is:

here is the scanrio i ran into and not sure how to resolve this.

let says, i am on page 7 on the mainpage.aspx and i click on the link and it will take me to user.aspx page and from the user.aspx when i click on the `BAck to Page` then it will take me to page but i will be landed on page 1 instead of page 7

how can i restore or maintain the page number and back to the same page where i come from?

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you handling the paging of GridView using AJAX or a pure old postback?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();" target="_self">Go Back Page</a>
```

If nothing works out you can always create a Session["PrevPage"] and store the previous page name in that session and use it when you click back. But thats not the preferred way though.

EDIT:
Using Session from aspx page.

```
<a href='<%=Session["PrevPage"]%>'>Back To Page</a>
```

Comment: did not work with `target="_self"`, even if i use Session how would i go to page n when i click back to page?

Comment: I have changed added the code where it shows how to use session with a link.

Comment: well... i understand to store the page number in the session but if i am on page n and how do i go to page n after the page loads?

Comment: Let's say you have two pages Page1 and Page2.

Now you click a button on Page1 which navigates you to Page2.
Onclick of that button you need set your session on code behind
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["PrevPage"] = "Page1.aspx";

        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
    }

And on Page2 you can access this Session to get its previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Session State is your friend. You can either store the result set into session along with the resultset page or you can just store the page in session and query the data.

I just cannot remember if you use page_int or preload event - one of them... It will work on page load....

As Wicked Coder said use Session["PrevPage"], fill it on page_loaded event, click event